# Navigation bar issue in sencha touch

Tags: sencha-touch-2

How do I came to know Current view.
Means, Basically what I want is when I navigate back and fort I want to get the current view.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Did you try Ext.Viewport.getActiveItem()??

Comment: But by using this how I came to Know which view is active.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try getActiveItem() method of navigationView like below

```
var currentActiveItem = navigationViewObj.getActiveItem();
```